# : and - characters not showing when applying drawtext

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to get the characters '-' and ':' to show up when I draw text on an image so I can have the date and time show up properly formatted. When I run the python code and all that to set up the text it is exactly how I want it, I printed it to the screen. When the command is run though, the date and time don't show, at least when I try drawing this: `2018-12-12 T03:20:40` What shows up on the image is `12 T`

This is an example of the ':' and '-' characters having a problem

```
ffmpeg -y -i TifImageLoc -vf vflip,drawtext=fontfile=C:WINDOWS\Fonts\sserife.fon:fontsize=200:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-texth-texth)/2:text="Hello\-\ \:World" -frranes:v 1 output1.tif
```

When this is run I want the result of `Hello- :World` to be drawn on the image, but the actual result is `Hello` perfectly centered on the picture

How do you draw the '-' and ':' to an image using FFmpeg so that a date in this `2018-12-12 T03:20:40` format can be on the image?

Comment: I might have found an answer to this question, I've been banging my head on the wall for the past couple hours trying to figure this out

Comment: Double escape the characters.

Comment: @Gyan I needed to triple escape them, `'\\\:'` and `'\\\-'` works